# Acceder a GUI desde un metodo async (Task)

Tags: c#, hilos, asincronismo

Trato de acceder a los controles del formulario desde un método Asíncrono pero me da error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

La variable estática "principal" contiene la instancia del `Form1` (la utilizo siempre para acceder a los controles desde cualquier parte del programa)

```
public class Datos
{
    public static Form1 principal = null;
}

class Proceso1
{
    Procesos proceso;
    Producto productos;
    ArrayList lista_respuesta;
    public async Task cargarAsync()
    {
        lista_respuesta = new ArrayList();
        proceso = new Procesos();
        lista_respuesta = await proceso.cargar_datos();

          await Task.Run(() =>
           {

                    for (int a = 0; a < lista_respuesta.Count; a++)
                    {
                        productos = (Producto)lista_respuesta[a];

                        Datos.principal.listBox1.Items.Add(productos.nombre);
                    }

           });
    }
}

class Procesos
{
    ArrayList lista_productos;
    Producto producto;
    MySqlCommand comando;
    MySqlDataReader datos;

    public async Task<ArrayList> cargar_datos()
    {

        lista_productos = new ArrayList();

        using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=rpos;"))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM productos";
            using (comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion))
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    datos = comando.ExecuteReader();
                    while (datos.Read())
                    {
                        producto = new Producto(datos["nombre"].ToString(), datos["codigo"].ToString(), datos["precio1"].ToString());
                        lista_productos.Add(producto);
                    }
                });

                return lista_productos;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Producto
{
    public string nombre;
    public string codigo;
    public string precio1;

    public Producto(string nombre,string codigo,string precio1)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.precio1 = precio1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como observación no veo donde asignas el formulario a tu: `public static Form1 principal = null;` Siempre tiene un valor `null`.

---

Su poniendo que tu variable `principal` no se vuelva nula en algún lugar del código u hagas otras cosas en el código que provoquen que te salte la excepción:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
public void ModificarUI(Action accion)
{
      if (InvokeRequired)
          Invoke(accion);
      else
          accion();
}
```

Para usarlo así:

```
//...
//...
ModificarUI(() =>
{
    Datos.principal.listBox1.Items.Add(productos.nombre);
});
//...
```

Comment: Cuandop creo una nueva instancia de Form1 en el metodo asincrono si funciona correctamente(obiamente se genera un segundo Form1)Creo que no funciona por el objeto de Form1 se creo en un subproceso diferente al metodo del otro hilo..como resolverlo ?

Comment: Obvio, pero si no asignas una instancia a `Form1` como vas a acceder a un objeto que este contenga?

Comment: Si tengo eso realizado:                                                                                                          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 formulario = new Form1();
            Application.Run(formulario);
            Datos.principal = formulario;

Comment: @Javier Ok ya veo, usa el Debugger para identificar porque exactamente te salta la excepción en esa línea, analizando tanto la variable `princiapal` como la `listBox1`. Si mi código no te funciona eliminaré mi respuesta.

Comment: No probe  tu codigo porque no se que exactamente hace.

Comment: @Javier Deberías probar..